# Making a navigation header only with the Roman numbers of my sections in LaTeX with beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes, navigation

I'm making a presentation with Beamer in LaTeX and I would like to have a two part header :

- In the first part, I would have all the numbers of all my sections in Roman. I also would like the number of the active section to be white as normal text and the other numbers to have some sort of lower opacity and be less visible. Also, each number would be a link redirecting to the page where the corresponding section starts. In fact, it is exactly like `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}%` but with the Roman number of the section instead of the name of the section.
- In the second part, I would have all the subsections of my active section but that's okay, I did it with `\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}`.

I have seen that in one of my course and it look like that:

[image: First image example]
[image: Second image example]
[image: Third image example]

Ignore the asterisk, I don't know what they mean.

I have looked in the [beamer documentation](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) at the header and footer part (8.2.1) but I didn't found anything interesting from my point of view.

I have tried a lot of pieces of code found on the internet and asked ChatGPT but for now, I'm stuck with this :

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot} \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}
```

And here is the full code :

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{lmodern}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}


\title{Presentation title}
\date{\today}
\author{A. Name\inst{1}}

\institute[Ex] % (optional)
{
    \inst{1}%
    Example\\
    Example
}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}
{\vfill}
{\vskip15pt}
{}
{}
\makeatother  

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot} \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Table of content}
      \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{5cm}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-2},currentsection,sectionstyle=show,subsectionstyle=show]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{5cm}
            \tableofcontents[sections={3-4},currentsection,sectionstyle=show,subsectionstyle=show]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
%   \begin{center}
%       \tableofcontents
%   \end{center}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}
    Lipsum
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Section 2}
    Lipsum
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}{Section 3}
    Lipsum
\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\begin{frame}{Section 4}
    Lipsum
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried asking for the source of one of the presentations with the style you're looking for? Or ask which theme is used and for the source, if it isn't a standard one?

Comment: That is in fact a really good idea! I'm gonna ask today!
And thank you for changing the tags, I'm new to stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redefine the `\beamer@section` macro and pass the roman section number (instead of the title) to the headline.

I marked the changed line with `<- changes made here` in the code below:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{lmodern}
%\usepackage[]{hyperref}


\title{Presentation title}
\date{\today}
\author{A. Name\inst{1}}

\institute[Ex] % (optional)
{
    \inst{1}%
    Example\\
    Example
}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}
{\vfill}
{\vskip15pt}
{}
{}
\makeatother  

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot} \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}


\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@section[#1]#2{%
  \GetTitleString{#1}%
  \let\@currentlabelname\GetTitleStringResult
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \ifblank{#2}%
    {\long\def\secname{#1}\long\def\lastsection{#1}}%
    {\global\advance\beamer@tocsectionnumber by 1\relax%
      \long\def\secname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@sectionintoc{\the\c@section}{#2}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
        {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}}%
    {\let\\=\relax\xdef\sectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\secname}}}%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@sectionpages{\the\beamer@sectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    \ifblank{#1}{}{%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\sectionentry{\the\c@section}{\expandafter\@Roman\c@section}{\the\c@page}{\secname}{\the\c@part}}}% <- changes made here
    }%
    \beamer@sectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \def\insertsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\sectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \edef\insertsectionhead{\noexpand\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{\unexpanded{#1}}}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\lastsubsection{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\secname}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}{2}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}\hyper@anchorend%
    \ifblank{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsections}{\beamer@atbeginsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Table of content}
      \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{5cm}
            \tableofcontents[sections={1-2},currentsection,sectionstyle=show,subsectionstyle=show]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{5cm}
            \tableofcontents[sections={3-4},currentsection,sectionstyle=show,subsectionstyle=show]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
%   \begin{center}
%       \tableofcontents
%   \end{center}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}{Section 1}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}
    Lipsum
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Section 2}
    Lipsum
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}{Section 3}
    Lipsum
\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\begin{frame}{Section 4}
    Lipsum
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I asked my teacher and he told me how he does. For each section, he adds a short name, like ```\section[I]{Section 1}```. Your solution is better because I do not have to name each section manually. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: @benjaminpotron You're welcome!